# converting match_parent to "0dp"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

When I use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or `android:layout_width="match_parent"` as height/width of children in Constraint Layout and build the Gradle file it automatically changes to `android:layout_height="0dp"` or `android:layout_widtht="0dp"` respectively.

Technically there is a huge difference between **0dp** and **match_parent**.

Most of the time it doesn't effect my layout but sometimes this thing completely destroy my Constraint Layout.

I don't know why this happens.
Please guide me.

Comment: "0dp" is the equivalent of "match_parent" in ConstraintLayout, read more here https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 7):

match_parent isn't supported in ConstraintLayout. If you want the same behavior, use 0dp and set constraints on each side to the parent.

Comment: If match_parent isn't supported the why make it an option in the drop down for layout_width and layout_height in the IDE? I'm not saying you're wrong (because clearly if you work for Google and your name keeps popping up answering ConstraintLayout questions, then you obviously know a lot about it). But I am saying that the whole current implementation for ConstraintLayout is a mess and currently unusable.

Comment: But what if I want my view height or width to be 0dp (with 0 as value) in ConstraintLayout? I can not use 0dp and 0px because it will acts as match_parent.

Answer (score 3):

> You should not use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp)

`match_parent` means `filling whats left` where as 0dp means `match constraints`. In ConstraintLayout, `match_parent` is not supported.

`match_parent` relies on it's parent for it's position (x,y & width/height) but 0dp can be defined by a constraint/position

Answer (score 0):

The way worked with me for putting a Relative item, under another element, with width matching parent is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/xxx"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/xxx"
    >
```