# ConstraintLayout automatically resized by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm new to Android and I've got problems designing a layout in Android Studio. I've found many related questions but none of them worked. Values of constraints are always hardcoded in dp by Android Studio according to the current preview size (Pixel, Nexus 7...).

**Code I write in the XML editor** (that works just fine on my phone):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.meanstreet.note.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.meanstreet.note.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bold"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/bold_button" />

...
```

**Code changed after I went to the Design tab** (that doesn't fit to my phone screen):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.meanstreet.note.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:context="com.meanstreet.note.MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bold"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/bold_button" />
...
```

The Slider is a custom view that extends RelativeLayout.

The hardcoded values in Slider depend on the selected phone for the preview in Android Studio, and the view is now out of my phone (if the selected phone was bigger) or with big margins on right and bottom (if the selected phone was smaller).

This seems very weird to me: I can still avoid going to the Design tab, that way the code won't be changed and will work on any device, but that's annoying.

Why is Android Studio behaving like that ? How can I have the width and height to stay at "match_parent", and so have the right size on any phone ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: " I've found many related questions but none of them worked." Which related questions did you find? What were the results when you attempted the suggested solutions? How does what you want differ from these results?

Comment: "How can I have the width and height to stay at "match_parent"?" Just set the width and height to "match_parent".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505641/android-constraintlayout-generates-absolute-values => says values aren't compiled in code, but it seems to be. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126678/android-studio-converting-match-parent-to-0dp => with 0dp, the Slider is not displayed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452384/android-studio-keeps-replacing-match-parent-with-fixed-dp-value => I tried infering constants but the results is worse, a margin half the size of the screen is inserted

Comment: @Code-Apprentice As soon as I go to the Design tab, these values are replaced by values in dp, as shown in the code I posted: that's the problem

Comment: Note that "dp" stands for "device independent pixels". When you specify a dp value, the size is adjusted depending on each device's screen size and resolution. If you do not want this behavior, there are many other ways to set the width and height of a view. You should read the documentation for `layout_height` and `layout_width`.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with those links and explanations.

Comment: You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134773/1440565) again. Notice the words after "and".

Comment: I've read the docs, and match_parent is definitively the behaviour I want: having my Slider using the full screen. But it impacts the size, as code for the Nexus 7 is out of my screen (which is smaller), and the code for the Pixel doesn't use all my screen (which is bigger). Thanks for your help, I can try it again and I'll comment the result

Comment: See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Remove all attributes with `tools:` prefix, then let us know how things look

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've replaced the parameters in Slider by:           android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent". Is that how I'm supposed to use it ? It stays at a size of zero.

Comment: @cricket_007 When I remove them, they're added again when I go to Design tab...

Comment: Well, it's trying to get you to use constraints, as that's what the layout is designed for. You're welcome to change the constraint layout for anything you want if that's the issue

Comment: @cricket_007 What can I use instead ? A RelativeLayout as base of the layout ? A ConstraintLayout is what is created by default and I didn't try to remove it, but it feels like a workaround rather than really understand what the problem is

Comment: By using the default, it's assumed you've been over this https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match_parent` is not supported for elements inside `ConstraintLayout`. Instead you can do;

- Set the Slider's width to `0dp`.
- Add constraints to left and right with these attributes.

  `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"`

  `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

This way you can stretch that view horizontally. You can do the same thing vertically with same logic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.meanstreet.note.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.meanstreet.note.MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bold"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/bold_button" />
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ConstraintLayout specifically. However, in general, "start" and "end" should be preferred to "left" and "right" to support all locales.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can set these parameters to the ConstraintLayout, but what do I put for the Slider ? Still match_parent ?

Comment: Nothing seems to work, no matter the constraints I set for left, right, start, end... The size of the ConstraintLayout stays at zero

Comment: @Mean-Street Those are for the slider actually. ConstraintLayout should stay match_parent, match_parent.

Comment: All right, that works! I thought that "match_parent not supported by ConstraintLayout" meant that I couldn't use it as width and height for it, but it's actually the elements inside it. Thanks a lot